# Return to proper hubsection when returning to mainpage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 App and my mainpage has a Hub control that consists of one (manually created) XAML hubsection and multiple dynamic hubsections generated from JSON. I have a button that takes the user to a new page. When the user returns to the mainpage it currently shows the user the first hubsection. I am trying to make it so the user returns and sees the hubsection that was focused on before.

I attempted:

```
        IList<HubSection> currentSections;
        currentSections = mainHub.SectionsInView;
        // Do your code
        mainHub.SectionsInView = currentSections;
```

but apparently `SectionsInView` is readonly. I can't find anything online... is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Hub.ScrollToSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.scrolltosection.aspx) method or the Hub.DefaultSectionIndex property

Comment: I decided to use the Hub.ScrollToSection and I am passing the selected HubSection through the pages through the Frame.Navigate(page, HubSection) and getting it in the OnNavigatedTo method ((HubSection)e.Parameter). Doing this it doesn't select the section I want (stays on first page)... but if I hardcode it to Hub.ScrollToSection(Hub.Sections[1]) it works... Is there a way to pass the hubsection and have it still work? I don't want to use index as that might change.

Comment: You can iterate Hub.Sections collection to find the section you want and then pass it to ScrollToSection

Comment: That's what I decided to do... Was hoping there was a better way, Thank you so much :)